# content not expanding vertically in div

Tags: html, overflow, hidden, expand

I have a site that i'm having issues with.  When (in the middle of the page) If you click on the second answer of the question 1 you will see that the content goes behind the parallax div.  It should be just moving that did down to expand the content in the other div.  I'm pretty stumped and not sure why this is doing this.
I have looked all other questions on the web pertaining to this question, like adding overflow:hidden, but this is not working.
Thanks,
Brian

http://clane.revvnrg.com/rewards

Comment: Site "Down For Maintenance".  it's better if you could recreate the issue using the provided Code Snippet tool in the editor or a third party solution like http://jsfiddle.net or http://jsbin.com

Comment: unfortunately I can't do that because it won't work correctly with all of the patent files and formulas.  if you give me your ip i can whitelist you to look at it.

Comment: Unfortunately That's not exactly how stackoverflow operates.  We as developers are happy to volunteer our knowledge toward solutions to clear and concise questions, but this is not a site for free contract work.  Unless you can [recreate the problem within the guidelines of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), there's unfortunately very little we can do.  There's not even a private messaging system build into the site, so there's no way for it to function as a contacting platform.